# How to detect url and replace it as link in contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to display 'google.com' every time users type it just like [google.com](https://www.google.com) like in facebook textarea when we post something. I am a newbie to web development. Please help! :)
This code is not working. :')

html:

```
<div data-text="true" id="textbox" contenteditable="true" style="width: 500px; background-color: blanchedalmond; outline: none;z-index:0;" aria-placeholder="true"></div>
```

javascript:

```
 $('#textbox').bind("keyup",function(event) {
            if(event.which == 32){
                console.log($(this).text()+'out')
             _text = $(this).text();
             text = _text.split(/\s+/).reverse()[1];
             console.log(text);
            if(text.match('google.com') == 'google.com') {
                console.log(text+'in');
                newText = "<a href='https://www.google.com/'>" + text + "</a>";
                _text = _text.replace(new RegExp(text + '$'), newText)
                $(this).html(_text);
                placeCaretAtEnd($(this).get(0));
            }
            }
        });
        function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
            el.focus();
            if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
                    && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
                var range = document.createRange();
                range.selectNodeContents(el);
                range.collapse(false);
                var sel = window.getSelection();
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
            } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
                var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
                textRange.moveToElementText(el);
                textRange.collapse(false);
                textRange.select();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you need use **append** function, at same time append to body or some specific structure.

The key is here:

```
$(this).text(text); //Removing the space from div.
$("body").append(newText); //Adding element to body.
```

When you press space the space introduced will be removed instantly and the **a** element will be added.

```js
$('#textbox').bind("keyup",function(event) {
            //console.log(event.which);
            if(event.which == 32){ //Space
                //console.log($(this).text()+'out')
             _text = $(this).text();
             text = _text.split(/\s+/).reverse()[1];
             console.log('"' + text + '"');
             let x = text.match(/^google.com|facebook.com|twitter.com$/g);
            if(x != null) {
                //console.log(text+'in');
                newText = `<a href='https://${x[0]}/'>${text}</a><br/>`;
                //_text = _text.replace(new RegExp(text + '$'), newText)
                //console.log(this);
                $(this).text(text); //Removing the space from div.
                $("body").append(newText); //Adding element to body.
                //console.log($(this).get(0));
                placeCaretAtEnd($(this).get(0)); //?
            }
            $(this).text("");
            }
        });
        function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
            el.focus();
            if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
                    && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
                var range = document.createRange();
                range.selectNodeContents(el);
                range.collapse(false);
                var sel = window.getSelection();
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
            } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
                var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
                textRange.moveToElementText(el);
                textRange.collapse(false);
                textRange.select();
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-text="true" id="textbox" contenteditable="true" style="width: 500px; background-color: blanchedalmond; outline: none;z-index:0;" aria-placeholder="true"></div>
```

Comment: After typing google.com can not type space :'). Not working! :')

Comment: Why you need the space in 1 url ?

Comment: I don't understand at all what you want in result, you want add the **a** element with href google.com when you have in text google.com ?

Comment: Yes, like facebook or other site

Comment: My question is why you use for example ``if(text.match('google.com') == 'google.com') {``  if you want add more sites ? Or you want specific sites like you tell, if its the case, you need use the OR operator in regex.

Comment: I will use it later just wanted to do the basics

Comment: Execute the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tbox').on('input', function() {
  if($('#tbox').val().toLowerCase() == 'google.com'){
   $('#out').text('https://google.com');
  };
});
```